# Get YEAR() on Doctrine2. Date with year, month, hour, mine and second

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm

i already have the Doctrine2 Extension to get YEAR(), and it works, but only if the DateTime has year, month and day. But mine has also hour, minute and second, so it won't work. Any ideas?

Working SQL example (fechaIngreso has (yyyy-mm-dd)):

```
$query8 = $em->createQuery('SELECT count(a.fechaIngreso) FROM ProcesoBundle:ProcesoDisciplinario a WHERE YEAR(a.fechaIngreso) = 2015');
```

Not Working SQL example (fechaToma has (yyyy-mm-dd-hour-minute-second)):

```
$query8 = $em->createQuery('SELECT count(b.fechaToma) FROM ProcesoBundle:ProcesoDisciplinario a, ActosBundle:ActoAdministrativo b WHERE a.niResDefinitivo = b.id AND YEAR(b.fechaToma) = 2015');
```

Comment: Which database engine are you working with?

Comment: I'm working with MySQL Workbench, but Symfony won't let me use SQL (Only DQL), that's why i had to extend a library to use the YEAR() function

Comment: Couldn't you use the [DATE() Extension](https://github.com/orocrm/doctrine-extensions) and apply `YEAR(DATE(...))`

Comment: I also find that there are many different Doctrine extensions out there, and wonder if some of them don't offer a `YEAR` function that works on DateTimes as well?